# Facebook open graph meta tags not working

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

In order to have a nicer look of my links to my website www.skisprungschanzen.com on the corresponding Facebook site www.facebook.com/skisprungschanzen, I wanted to add Open Graph tags to the website headers.

However, the og-tags are not recognized by FB and the lint tool even has problems reading the website (response code 503) (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.skisprungschanzen.com, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.skisprungschanzen.com)

What could be the reasons therefore or what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your domain name to your app. Edit your app and in "Website with Facebook Login" specify http://www.skisprungschanzen.com in "Site Url"